# how to find what events overlap a date in icalendar in python?

Tags: python, icalendar

Question is pretty much in the title.
I have an event :

```
from icalendar import Event
from datetime import datetime
# every day from 8am to 12pm
ev = Event(dtstart=datetime(2013,11,22,8), dtend=datetime(2013,11,22,12), rrule='freq=daily')

# tomorrow 10am
d = datetime(2013, 11, 23, 10)
```

does ev overlap/contains d ? What is the function I should use ?
I strangely don't find anything in icalendar's unit tests

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but IIRC icalendar just does parsing and serialisation of icalendar file, it doesn't do interpretation of rules and the like.

For that, you want [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)'s dateutil.rrule. And it will only do recurrence rule computation, it doesn't have an Event interface so you have to perform these steps separately.

Comment: dateutil seems to work fine with dates and recurrence rules (e.g every 1st monday of the month), but not with events (date with a from 8am to 12pm every monday) ; rules have a dtstart but no dtend. Do you remember anything ?